# Installing OpenGL/GLUT & running C program?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I'm new to OpenGL and GLUT and need help installing them and running hello.c (see below) in Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition.

I'm using Windows XP and was reading on the [OpenGL wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started) that the OpenGL Library is already installed on my computer. As a result, I only downloaded [GLUT for Win32 dll, lib and header file](http://www.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html) and extracted it.

I have 4 questions:

1. If OpenGL is already installed, how do I find it and use it in my Visual C++ project?
2. The [OpenGL wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started) mentioned that opengl32.dll is located in windows/system32 folder - so what do I do with this dll?
3. Do I just add glut.h to Visual C++ Solution Explorer's header files folder?
4. Where do I put glut32.dll, glut32.lib and glut.def?

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

hello.c was taken from OpenGL Programming Guide [Chapter 1](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter01.html)

```
// hello.c renders a white rectangle on a black background
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display(void)
{
    // clear all pixels
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //  draw white polygon with corners at (0.25,0.25,0.0) and (0.75,0.75,0.0)    
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(0.25,0.25,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75,0.25,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75,0.75,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.25,0.75,0.0);
    glEnd();   

    // don't wait, start processing buffered OpenGL routines
    glFlush();
}

void init(void)
{
    // select clearing (background) color   
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    // initialize viewing values
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0);
}

/*
    Declare initial window size, position, and display mode
    (single buffer and RGBA). Open window with "hello"
    in its title bar. Call initiaization routines. 
    Register callback function to display graphics.
    Enter main loop and process events

*/

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250,250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutreateWindow("Hello");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0; // ISO C requires main to return int   
}
```

Comment: I found out the wiki has explained clearly most of your questions. In Visual Studio IDE, it is just a matter of putting the correct headers as the IDE installation has provided the Windows OpenGL support except the GLUT library. You just need to add a new reference to the GLUT library inside your project configuration. Normally, you don't need to worry on where to find those OpenGL DLLs in Windows system files. Even, the wiki describes the way to access the latest OpenGL extensions in your OpenGL codes as Windows has never updated its OpenGL version (still 1.1)

Comment: Thanks for comment. But I am using it on Mac, not Windows system.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate question, see [Using GLUT with Visual C++ Express Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264/using-glut-with-visual-c-express-edition).

Apart from that: I would definitely consider using the Simple DirectMedia Layer (http://www.libsdl.org/) as a more modern and frequently updated replacement for the venerable GLUT.

Comment: I've found this question. But I don't think it's duplicate because I'm using Mac system rather than Windows one. The setting should be different?